# Android cannot render some JPG files. How do I know what attribute it is that causes this, so that I exclude them from cursor resutls?

Tags: android

I am creating a gallery application and I uploaded 200 images on my phone to test with. Some of them appear as blank thumbnails in my app and in the device's native gallery as well. They are regular JPG files and on my computer I can see them just fine.

How do I exclude these images that will not be rendered, when requesting media from MediaStore here?

```
ArrayList<String> mediaStoreColumns = new ArrayList<>();

    if (cursorID == CURSOR_LOADER_THUMBS) {
        mediaStoreColumns.add(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        mediaStoreColumns.add(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN);
        mediaStoreColumns.add(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
    }

    return new CursorLoader(GalleryActivity.this,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            mediaStoreColumns.toArray(new String[mediaStoreColumns.size()]), null, null,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Here is one of the files:
[image]

Here is its information:

[image]
[image]

And this is an excerpt from the logs:

```
07-21 14:55:42.674 4469-5489/com.asd.android V/MediaStore: Create the thumbnail in memory: origId=10105, kind=1, isVideo=false
07-21 14:55:42.704 4469-5485/com.asd.android D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
07-21 14:55:42.714 4469-5489/com.asd.android D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
```

EDIT:
This is the code I use to obtain thumbnails:

```
thumbnailBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    imageIdInMediaStore,
                    12345,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                    null);
```

So basically I need to filter out images that do not have a Thumbnail in the media store - how do I do that?

Comment: There is indeed something funny with that picture. I could see it in FireFox on my PC. But right click on it and choose to show it () it was blank. But choosing to save it to file then Irfanview displays it ok. But after reloading this page the picture is invisible.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the same thing too

Comment: Then why didn't you tell?

Comment: I noticed that after you describd it. Even If I had noticed it before, we already know that there is a problem with the image, so saying it again wouldntve been very beneficial

Comment: You get a blank thunbnail. But is it blank or is the pointer null?

Comment: The bitmap returned is null. I inserted a check if it is null and now I am manually decoding the image, but the result is also null.

Comment: Well if it is null you are done i think. Problem solved.

Comment: But then how does Android native Gallery display the image when I click on it in the File explorer? In the file explorer the thumbnail is missing like in my app, but when I click the image it opens.. so there is image data

Comment: How would i know? Wich Android version is able to show it? Copied the file to a phone. ES File Explorer on Android 4.4 cannot show the icon. And the Gallery complains that it cannot generate a thumbnail. It does not show ps88R.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail` may be wrong.
It will be worth to try [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) (or other image libraries).

like this:

```
    int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    String path = cursor.getString(dataColumn);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(path) // or .load(new File(path))
            .resize(thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Picasso wasn't able to render the image as well. Get thumbnail is not wrong because it worked for hundreds of images with the exception of these few ones.